# (p <- ncol(X)) == ncol(Y) is not TRUE error in glmer

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to fit a model with a `glmer` and I keep getting the error:

> Error : (p <- ncol(X)) == ncol(Y) is not TRUE

It's a large model, with 8 features and several thousand points. When researching this bug, I found that it could be caused by too many `NA`s. I looked at my features, and only one of them had any `NA`s. I then excluded that feature from my model, but I still I got the error. The data is too large and cannot be posted.

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-from-lme4-quot-Error-p-lt-ncol-X-ncol-Y-is-not-TRUE-quot-td4712617.html

The model is as follows:

```
covariates=c("Sex", "PC1", "PC2", "PC3", "PC4", "label", "Alive")

fix.eff=paste("outcome","~",xi)

if (!is.null(covariates)) {for (covi in covariates)  fix.eff=paste(fix.eff,"+",covi) }

fix.eff=formula(paste(fix.eff, "+(1|",ind.family,")")) 

fit <- try(glmer(fix.eff,family=binomial(link='logit'), data=x))
```

Comment: It will be hard to troubleshoot without a reproducible example.  Do you get the same error if you simply write out the model in `glmer` "by-hand" rather than constructing the formula as you are now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the following line:

```
fix.eff=formula(paste(fix.eff, "+(1|",ind.family,")"))
```

it should have been

```
fix.eff=formula(paste(fix.eff, "+(1| ind.family)"))
```

`ind.family` is a column in the data set `x.` The original way it was written, it was read in as its current value, instead of the column. So the formula included the term `(1|1)` instead of `(1|ind.family)`. Now that it's fixed, it  works!

If anyone else gets this error, I would recommend looking very closely at your formula and your data to make sure it is what you think it is.