# "Error in KhatriRao(sm, t(mm)) : (p <- ncol(X)) == ncol(Y) is not TRUE" in glmer even after previous solutions answers tried

Tags: r, lme4, glmm

I know a question with this exact same question has been asked previously, but previous answers have come up with two possible answers, neither of which I think is applicable in this case. In the first one, there were NA values, and I have already checked and found no NA values. In the other there was an issue in the formula being used before constructing the glmer, but I am not being so clever and am instead trying to make it by hand. What I have is the following:

`glmer(data$Changed_Use ~ data$Country + data$Sex + data$Age + data$Birthplace_Residence + (1|data$Place),data = data, family = binomial)`

Where data$Place is a list of locations where the data collection occurred. I have tried both having it as the actual names, and giving the locations numerical codes (first location being 1, second location being 2, etc) and both cases have gotten the same error message. What is the error in my notation, and how do I fix it?

*** Thanks to Ben Bolker for figuring out how to solve the issue. This is part of a wider study where more information was collected than what was being used for this model. I am including the relevant data for this model here, so that perhaps others can see how this error occurred to begin with.

```
tibble [221 × 49] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Place                   : num [1:221] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Country                 : num [1:221] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Sex                     : chr [1:221] 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0...
 $ Age                     : num [1:221] 35 27 54 22 35 35 50 39 38 45 ...
 $ Birthplace_Residence    : num [1:221] 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Changed_Use             : num [1:221] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
```

Comment: It would be helpful if your question links to the previous questions/answers. I can't say anything for sure without a [mcve], but the first thing to try is to get rid of all of the `data$` entries in the formula, i.e. make your formula `Changed_Use ~ Country + Sex + Age + Birthplace_Residence + (1|Place)` ? Using `data$` **shouldn't** break anything, but not using it is best practice for a variety of reasons ...

Comment: I found this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663394/p-ncolx-ncoly-is-not-true-error-in-glmer?rq=2  and this one https://github.com/neuropsychology/psycho.R/issues/58 and this fixed bug: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/246

Comment: (Also, best not to call your data frame "data": it *can* sometimes lead to obscure errors ...)

Comment: Ah alright, I was referring to past instances where this problem seems to have been asked, namely here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663394/p-ncolx-ncoly-is-not-true-error-in-glmer . Your suggestion worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: It would be great if you can (1) write up an answer and post it (you may have to wait a bit before you're allowed to answer your own question) and (2) post `summary(data)` or `str(data)`.  I'm really curious how you were able to make this error happen!

Comment: The data is part of a larger dataset of interviews collected during fieldwork, so I am only including the lines relevant to the question I was asking here: tibble [221 × 49] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Place                   : num [1:221] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Country                 : num [1:221] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Sex                     : chr [1:221] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
 $ Age                     : num [1:221] 35 27 54 22 35 35 50 39 38 45 ...

Comment: what is `Changed_Use`?  I don't see it (nor `Birthplace_Residence`) in your tibble (could you please edit that info into your question? Maybe even the output of `dput()` using the first few rows and the relevant columns ...

Comment: I have added the information to the question, hope it gives you an inkling as to how the error occurred!

Comment: do you get the same error in a clean R session? (i.e., only `lme4` loaded and this particular data set defined, nothing else in your workspace)?

Answer (score 0):

For the record: this problem was solved by removing the `data$` references in the formula, i.e.

```r
glmer(Changed_Use ~ Country + Sex + Age + Birthplace_Residence + 
   (1|Place),data = data, family = binomial)
```

which is best practice in any case. However, the problem wasn't reproducible so it's hard to see exactly *why* this was failing ...